# Mocks data doesn't update in @ApplicationScoped cdi when running Arquillian tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I am writing arquillian unit test (using @RunWith(AdnWildflyArquillianForUnitTests.class) combined with mockito) for my cdi bean (application scoped).
Here is snippet of my test class:

```
@Inject
private MyCdiBean bean;

@Mocks
@Produces
private static MyService service; // this service is called inside beanMethod

private ServiceDTO dto;
@Before
public void initData() {
   dto = new ServiceDTO();
   when(service.callServiceMethod(any())).thenReturn(dto);
}

@Test
public void test1() {
  dto.setFlag(true);
  bean.callBeanMethod();
}
@Test
public void test2() {
  dto.setFlag(false);
  bean.callBeanMethod();
}
```

If i run the single test method, it works fine. But when i run test class, the dto return in test2 has value the same as dto return in test1 (although i modified value before the bean is called). If i change cdi to @RequestScope, it works fine. So i think the cdi somehow cache state of my mocks. I tried vairous way, but still not know how to fix it (i don't want to change my cdi scope). 
Is there any way to clear the state in cdi or to make the mocks return new value? Please give me some hint.
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the CDI container is booted only once and then it executes both test methods on it. If that would be the case, application scoped beans will remember their state throughout secondary test.

Comment: yes, I know. How can I refresh the state?

Comment: I don't know enough about your deployment to tell. If it's SE environment, than you should make sure that for each test method you create and shutdown CDI container. If it's EE than I think Arquillian could handle this by redeploying the archive for each method (hence re-booting the app and your CDI stuff along with it).

Comment: I takes time to restart the container as there are many classes depend on it. But i refactored the code, moved all the implement to Stateless Bean. Therefore, my problem was solved. I just curious how the state is cached and how to deal with it.

Comment: Then you got rid of app scoped and replaced it with `@Dependent` (that's what CDI uses for `@Stateless`). And with dependent/stateless, you create new instance for each call, so the state is not cached. As for caching of state with app scoped - it holds the state for the duration of the CDI container life, or until you deactivate the scope (which would be weird practice in case of this one).

Comment: You searched for a solution in Arquillian, I know. We decided to use a kind of extended cdi-unit, which might help as well [ejb-cdi-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit). In that case the Testclass including the cdi-container gets created for each single test. That I can guarantee.